Unable to delete Firebase App Hosting Backends for failed deployments. No option to delete in dashboard
I need help to delete my backend from firebase hosting.
I initially tried to deploy by linking my project from github, but the deploy failed multiple times. I want to try and delete my backend from the dashboard, and reconnect, but there is no option to delete.
I later tried to deploy via the terminal: firebase deploy which was successful, but my intial failed attempts via github are still showing in my dashboard.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Ew9vVWZP.jpg)
Selecting project backend does not have an option to delete or unlink.

go to fire base console
then click your project
in left hand coner there is hosting tab
click the three dot and delete.
After delete you can go to github action under the hosting tab go to connected git hub repo section and disconect your project.
try this way if your not tried yet.

Hey, thanks for the response.
When I click on my project backend card under the "App hosting" nothing happens (likely because the backend Rollout failed).   Also, there is sadly no 3 dots on the card. (Which is super frustrating).
If i click "View Dashboard" on the App Hosting backend card, and click the 3 dots, there is no option to delete.
I have gone in circles for hours but I still can't find a way to delete the failed rollouts.

Hi @LorenCouse you can also use firebase apphosting:backends:delete -l us-central1 my-backened-id to delete the app hosting backend, reference this answer
